# Wordpress Get Category From Post Table

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

I am trying to display last couple of post title in a comma separated value with below code.Here I am making the query from `wp_post` table.Now How can I get the category in this code as there is no column for `category` in `wp_post`table. below is my code

```
 <?php
      $posts = $wpdb->get_col("
      SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
      FROM $wpdb->posts
      WHERE post_status = 'publish' 
      and post_type='post'

      ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 10");

      $the_posts = array();
      foreach($posts as $post) :
      echo implode( ', ', $the_posts );
  ?>
```

Comment: Where's the csv?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

1 - get posts (correct way for wp)

```
<?php 
     $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 10,
    'orderby'          => 'date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

2 - loop the posts and get categories

```
foreach($posts_array as $post):setup_postdata($post);
     $category = get_the_category();
     var_dump($category);
endforeach;
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: just add ; after setup_postdata($post)

Comment: works! but how can i get post title in comma separated value from specific category like cat_id in 2,3,4 etc

Comment: you can use get_the_category_by_ID( int $cat_ID )

Comment: and then get posts from that category <?php $args = array(
 'posts_per_page'   => 10,
 'category'         => $category_id,
 'orderby'          => 'date',
 'order'            => 'DESC',
 'post_type'        => 'post',
 'post_status'      => 'publish',
 'suppress_filters' => true 
);
$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>